# Can you use a BindingAdapter on a ViewStub?

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I want to create an "inflateWhen" BindingAdapter and attach it to a viewstub to have it inflate when a boolean value is true.  However, the BindingAdapter keeps trying to operate on the root view of the viewstub, causing it to fail to compile.  Is there any way to do this as a bindingadapter rather than having to do it programmatically in the activity?

Here's what I have so far:

```
@BindingAdapter("inflateWhen")
fun inflateWhen(viewstub: ViewStub, inflate: Boolean) {
    if (inflate) {
        viewstub.inflate()
    } else {
        viewstub.visibility = View.GONE
    }
}
```

This is what I have, but when attached to a viewstub like

```
<ViewStub
    android:id="@+id/activity_footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:inflateWhen="@{viewmodel.userid != 0}" />
```

it fails to compile.  The error is:

```
ActivityMyAccountSectionedBindingImpl.java:1087: error: cannot find symbol
            if (this.pageFooter.isInflated()) this.pageFooter.getBinding().setVariable(BR.inflateWhen, viewmodelRatingInt0);
```

Looks like it's trying to apply the binding to the inflated view, but that's not what I want here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**08.10.2020 Update:**

I have written an article on Medium where I provide an example of how to switch between layouts on the fly depending on the screen state using ViewStub and DataBinding:

https://medium.com/@mxdiland/viewstub-databinding-handle-screen-states-easily-2f1c01098b87

**Old accepted answer:**

I also faced the problem to write `@BindingAdapter` for the `ViewStub` to control layout inflation using databinding instead of direct referencing to the `ViewStub` and calling `inflate()`

Along the way, I did some investigation and studied the following things:

- `ViewStub` must have `android:id` attribute to avoid build errors like **java.lang.IllegalStateException: target.id must not be null**;
- any custom attribute declared for ViewStub in an XML, databinding tries to set as a variable to the layout which will be inflated instead of the stub;
- ... that's why any binding adapter is written for `ViewStub` will never be used by databinding
- there is only one but pretty tricky `@BindingAdapter` which works: `androidx.databinding.adapters.ViewStubBindingAdapter` and allows setting `ViewStub.OnInflateListener` trough XML attribute `android:onInflate`
- the `ViewStubBindingAdapter`'s first argument is `ViewStubProxy` not `View` or `ViewStub`!;
- any different adapter written similarly does not work - databinding tries to set variable to the future layout instead of using the adapter
- BUT it is allowed to override existing `androidx.databinding.adapters.ViewStubBindingAdapter` and implement some desired logic.

Because this adapter is one and the only option to interact with `ViewStub` using databinding I decided to override the adapter and use not for its intended purpose

The idea is to provide specific `ViewStub.OnInflateListener` which will be the listener itself and at the same time will be a signal that `ViewStub.inflate()` should be called:

```
class ViewStubInflationProvoker(
    listener: ViewStub.OnInflateListener = ViewStub.OnInflateListener { _, _ ->  }
) : ViewStub.OnInflateListener by listener {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun provideIf(clause: Boolean): ViewStubInflationProvoker? {
            return if (clause) {
                ViewStubInflationProvoker()
            } else {
                null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and overriding binding adapter:

```
@BindingAdapter("android:onInflate")
fun setOnInflateListener(
    viewStubProxy: ViewStubProxy,
    listener: ViewStub.OnInflateListener?
) {
    viewStubProxy.setOnInflateListener(listener)

    if (viewStubProxy.isInflated) {
        viewStubProxy.root.visibility = View.GONE.takeIf { listener == null } ?: View.VISIBLE
        return
    }

    if (listener is ViewStubInflationProvoker) {
        viewStubProxy.viewStub?.inflate()
    }
}
```

and XML part

```
...
<ViewStub
    android:id="@+id/no_data_stub"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout="@layout/no_data"
    android:onInflate="@{ViewStubInflationProvoker.provideIf(viewModel.state == State.Empty.INSTANCE)}"
    app:viewModel="@{viewModel.noDataViewModel}"
    />
...
```

So now the inflation will happen only when the state is `State.Empty` and databinding will set **viewModel** variable to the inflated `@layout/no_data` layout.

Not really graceful but working solution.